# How to delete Folders created with PHP mkdir?

Tags: php, linux, mkdir

I have created folders using PHP's mkdir command. 
Now I want to delete these folders over FTP or SSH.

I get the error "permission denied".
I am on a managed server so I do not have root access.

What can I do so I will be able to delete these folders? 
Do I need to change the file permissions (chmod) using PHP?

Comment: What host is it? It may be something as simple as they have turned off the ability to use unlink() (assuming you are using that), or that the way they have permissions set up makes it possible to create but not delete. We need more information to give you a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folders would have been created with the ownership/permissions of whatever account PHP was running under (Apache's, if you're doing this from a web-based script).

You wouldn't be able to chown the directories to another account, as that requires root permissions. You could have the script that creates the directories set them to mode 0777, which'd give everyone read/write/delete access to them, but you might not want to open up things that wide.

Answer (score 2):

you have to change the permissions first:

> chmod("/somedir/somefile", 755);

or whatever you like
then you can remove with

> rmdir("dir")

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must run chmod after directory or file creation with PHP. Its because PHP runs with Apache permissions.

After chmod to PHP/Apache user you can rename, move or delete folders and files.

Answer (score 1):

Check your permission first if you got any problem. Some folder you only can delete or chmod if you are owner.
If you are owner, then you can use PHP chmod.

```
CHMOD("PATH_TO_FOLDER",0755);
```

Then use unlink to delete files in folder:

```
unlink("PATH_TO_FOLDER/*.*");
```

And then

```
rmdir("PATH_TO_FOLDER")
```